# Getting error while running rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, azure, rubygems

I am migrating my web app to Microsoft Azure. When I do rails s, I am getting this log:

```
/home/mnpatel0611/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:282: warning: circular argument reference - now
/home/mnpatel0611/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puppet-3.7.3/lib/puppet/defaults.rb:465: warning: duplicated key at line 466 ignored: :queue_type
/home/mnpatel0611/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puppet-3.7.3/lib/puppet/vendor/safe_yaml/lib/safe_yaml/syck_node_monkeypatch.rb:42:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Syck (NameError)
    from /home/mnpatel0611/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puppet-3.7.3/lib/puppet/vendor/safe_yaml/lib/safe_yaml.rb:197:in `<module:YAML>'
    from /home/mnpatel0611/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puppet-3.7.3/lib/puppet/vendor/safe_yaml/lib/safe_yaml.rb:132:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/mnpatel0611/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puppet-3.7.3/lib/puppet/vendor/require_vendored.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/mnpatel0611/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puppet-3.7.3/lib/puppet/vendor.rb:40:in `require_libs'
    from /home/mnpatel0611/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puppet-3.7.3/lib/puppet/vendor.rb:53:in `load_vendored'
    from /home/mnpatel0611/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puppet-3.7.3/lib/puppet.rb:172:in `<module:Puppet>'
    from /home/mnpatel0611/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puppet-3.7.3/lib/puppet.rb:29:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/mnpatel0611/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from /home/mnpatel0611/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/mnpatel0611/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /home/mnpatel0611/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /home/mnpatel0611/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /home/mnpatel0611/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /home/mnpatel0611/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.0/lib/bundler.rb:133:in `require'
    from /home/mnpatel0611/mapial-stage/mapial/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/mnpatel0611/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `require'
    from /home/mnpatel0611/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/mnpatel0611/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
    from /home/mnpatel0611/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Anyone face this error?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow.  here we expect you to: have a bit of a google to see if you can see if anybody else has had this question (then tell us what research you've done and why it was unsatisfactory) to show us that you have put some effort into researching it yourself. Then... you need to edit your question and add all *relevant* code to your original question (don't post code in comments, the formatting is awful).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puppatlabs describe that Puppet 3.7.3 is not supported on Ruby 2.2 but now thay change status to resolved. So you should go more into this and find rid of this problem. You can show this issue from puppatlabs ticket [Puppet 3.7.3 is not supported on Ruby 2.2](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-3796)